# Worksheet as a variable?

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a glorified copy and paste macro that copies imported information from a "template" worksheet into worksheets of specific locations. 
(so I have worksheets named location1 location2 location3 location4 and template)

Currently, my code looks like this: (but a lot longer and more repetitive)

```
 Sheets("Template").Select
 Range("P24:Q30").Select
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets("location1").Select
 Range("P24").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
```

I want the "location1" to be a worksheet variable.

I need a way for that to be changed without having to change the code for every different template. 
As far as I can see there are two solutions.

1. There is a cell in the template that holds the value of the name of the sheet that the information is supposed to be pasted into. If I could set this equal to a worksheet variable that I can write instead of the "Location1"
2. Have the user choose the Location worksheet from a list upon running the macro.

I don't know how to do either of these and I don't know which would be better.

Answer (score 1):

First, removing `select` is usually a good thing:

```
Sheets("Template").Range("P24:Q30").Copy Sheets("location1").Range("P24")
```

If your tab name is in cell `B1' of the sheet template, you can use:

```
dim sTabName as String

sTabName=Sheets("Template").[B1]
Sheets("Template").Range("P24:Q30").Copy Sheets(sTabName).Range("P24")
```

You can also create a real variable for your worksheet, e.g.

```
dim shtDest as Worksheet

set shtDest =sheets(Sheets("Template").[B1])
Sheets("Template").Range("P24:Q30").Copy shtDest.Range("P24")
```

Comment: nutsch, thanks for your help. 
The select thing is definitely better. 
I tried both of your solutions and I keep getting errors on both of them.

for the Worksheet thing I get runtime error 13 "type mismatch" with the Set shtDest line.

for the string thing i get runtime error 9 - subscript out of range. 

sorry I am very new at this...

Comment: You'll get this error if, in the Template Sheet, the cell B1 doesn't contain a valid sheet name.

Answer (score 0):

You can give variables value from a cell in a worksheet in VBA with the following:

```
Sub example()
    'Let vba know that you have a variable and it's type is string
    Dim myVariable as string

    'Assign the value from cell B5 in Worksheet "Template" to the variable
    myVariable = Sheets("Template").Range("B5").value
End sub()
```

You can loop through a range of cells and get their values as well.

```
Sum example()
    Dim myVariable as string

    'Let VBA know that we will store a range in variable "MyCell"
    Dim myCell as Range

    'loop through every cell in a range
    For each myCell in Sheets("Template").Range("B5:B100")

        'copy data from the template to the worksheet stored in the cell we are on
        Sheets(myCell.Value).Range("P24:Q30") = Sheets("Template").Range("P24:Q30")

    Next myCell
End Example()
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I'm getting runtime error 9 on the     myVariable line. thoughts? also, what is the purpose of looping through the cells?

Comment: For @JNevill's code, you'll get this error if, in the Template Sheet, the cell B5 doesn't contain a valid sheet name